# How can I forbid access to the root (“/ var / www”) of projects in ubuntu using apache, but can access “/ var / www / example”?

Tags: apache, ubuntu, lamp

I have a LAMP environment with ubuntu and I want to prohibit access to the root `/var/www`, but you can enter projects that are within the root `/var/www/example`

Prohibited access

```
/var/www
```

Access granted

```
/var/www/example
```

Comment: Off topic because its not about programming, but I'll answer anyway

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear all permissions on `/var/www` and give them explicitly to each project inside `/var/www`

```
chmod -R a-rwx /var/www
chown -R <www-user>:<www-group> /var/www/example
chmod -R ug+rwx /var/www/example
```

[chmod](https://linux.die.net/man/1/chmod), [chown](https://linux.die.net/man/1/chown)